# rewrite url /blog/article.php?id=hello to /blog/hello.html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Im having some troubles with the redirection rules on my .htaccess file.
I would like to create a rule to redirect my blog content to a friendly url.
The current url structure is:

> /blog/article.php?id=hello

and I would like it to change to:

> /blog/hello.html

This are my rules so far, and I dont seem to be able to find the error:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)$.html blog/article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I happen to solve it with a htaccess generator. The rule was:

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)\.html$ /blog/articulo.php?id=$1 [L]

The generator I used is: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because of your placement of `$` in the pattern, the rewrite module is unable to match your request to the expression.

It should be:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/([\da-z]+)\.html$ blog/article.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work to me. Im working with Apache 2.4.
Im trying both in a localhost server and on my real web page, no difference.
Any idea about what could I do? Thanks.